# IIS not serving .net control (.dll)

Tags: .net, user-controls, mime-types, iis-5

I'm serving a .net user control in .dll form.

It displays in IE7 fine when served from my external IIS 6 server.

However when served from a IIS 5 the **control is rendered as a Text Area control with a Scrollbar control on the side**.

I had a look at the http response - IIS5 is serving this:

```
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>
 The specified procedure could not be found. 
</body></html>
```

Any ideas why this is so?

I've tried adding the following mime types to the HTTP header configuration:

```
  .dll = application/x-msdownload

  .dll.config = text/html
```

Ash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aw man!

The .dll wasn't registered on the server!!!

`regasm mydll.dll /tlb`

Comment: are you answering to your own questions and also voting it up? :)